# Colour of boxplot based on order in graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, boxplot

I have made a boxplot of some of my data, where the x-axis contains behavioural categories, and the y-axis contains a value (ODBA). I have reordered the behavioural categories to be plotted from lowest ODBA to highest ODBA.

```
df1 %>% mutate(class=fct_reorder(Behaviour, ODBA, .fun="median")) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=reorder(Behaviour, ODBA), y=ODBA, fill=Behaviour)) +
   geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + theme(legend.position="none") +
   xlab("Behaviour") + ylab("ODBA (g)") +
   theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="white",colour="black")) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="YlOrRd")
```

[image: Click here for plot]

Now the boxplot colours are coloured based on the alphabetical order of the Behaviour variable. Is it possible to colour the boxplots with the palette based on the order they appear in the graph, so the behaviour to the far left (lying) will be yellow, while the behaviour to the far right will be red (Active)?

Comment: Use `fill = reorder(Behaviour, ODBA)` instead of `fill = Behaviour`.